# Primer mottling, is it getting absorbed into the wood?

Tags: painting

I have been having trouble priming some hardwood boards. The primer goes on fine, but after about 15 minutes, it begins to take on a mottled appearance and you can see the wood again. So, either the paint is pooling and migrating into clumps or it is getting absorbed into the wood, not sure which.

The wood is supele and the primer is an finely ground oil based base coat made by Fine Paints of Europe.

What is going here and what should I do if anything to correct the problem?

Comment: Is it just absorbing into the varying grain at different speeds?

Comment: If you have a test scrap, try sealing the wood with a pigmented shellac.  Kilz is a commonly used brand.  (Not the water based product of the same name.)

Comment: @jbbenni, were getting into shopping territory, but I'm not aware of a Kilz branded shellac primer.  If they make one, I don't think it is very common.  Zinsser BIN is the one I normally see.

Comment: Kills and Zinsser bin are 2 major brands used in the U.S.  I agree maybe the OP is applying two much primer? Or was there an oil base on the wood and now a latex primer , I have seen issues with this combination. I use Zinsser more often and it has not let me down.

Comment: You may want to browse the [finishing] and [staining] tags at [woodworking.se] - there's a _ton_ of information there about various finishing issues.

Answer (score 1):

Supele has a lot of natural oils in it, similar to some types of Mahogany or even Ipe, making it great for outdoor applications, including decks and even boat building. However, because of the natural oils, it will repel finishes and give the finish you described (a picture might help). Try sanding it smooth, then wiping it off with mineral spirits before attempting to paint again.

This still might not solve your issue and a coat of shellac as recommended by @jbbenni might be necessary to seal it prior to painting.